# Calling a parallelized executable with MATLAB 'dos' command behaves differently from the standalone executable

Tags: c++, matlab, parallel-processing

When I attempt to call a parallelized executable with MATLAB's `dos()` command, it won't run the executable and returns an error.

On its own, this simple C++ program runs exactly as you would expect:

```
/* Serial.exe */

#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    std::cout << "Apple!\n";
    std::cout << "Banana!\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Result:

```
Apple!
Banana!
```

So does this one:

```
/* Parallel */

#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << "Apple!\n";

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    {
        std::cout << "Banana!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Apple!
Banana!
Banana!
Banana!
Banana!
Banana!
Banana!
Banana!
Banana!
```

Now, I try to call both of these programs with the following MATLAB script:

```
%%  MATLAB call script

exe_path_1 = 'C:\\Users\\Jim\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Serial.exe';
exe_path_2 = 'C:\\Users\\Jim\\Documents\\MATLAB\\Parallel.exe';

rtn_1 = dos(exe_path_1)
rtn_2 = dos(exe_path_2)
```

Result:

```
Apple!
Banana!
rtn_1 = 0
rtn_2 = -1.0737e+09
```

What is it about MATLAB's `dos()` command that causes my parallel C++ code to fail?

Comment: It could be executing properly but only returning the final output. What happens if you use `rtn_2 = dos(exe_path_2,'-echo')` or `[rtn_2,cmdout_2] = dos(exe_path_2)`?

Comment: Using `'-echo'` does not change the outcome.  `[rtn_2, cmdout_2]` yields the same value of `rtn_2` and an empty string.

Comment: Which Matlab version? Some older versions IIRC don't turn multithreading on by default, you have to set it in the Preferences.

Comment: I'm using MATLAB version R2012b.

Comment: @Jim Works on my computer. Matlab R2012a, Windows 7.

Comment: Fascinating that you don't even get the 'Apple!'.... Could you use try the following: make an endless `while(1)` loop after the first Apple, and see if the program freezes, or it exits. If it exits, then we know that the program actually crashes before "Apple". If it freezes, then we know that it's doing the loop but not generating output.

Comment: If it does freeze, then you could then find out what's going on by attaching an external debugger to the process.

Comment: It happened to me after applying Matlab Update. Before update, everything was working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a similar issue calling the command via java. Here is some m-code which uses the java classes:

```
rt = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();
pr = rt.exec(command);
input= java.io.BufferedReader(java.io.InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
while(1)
    f=(input.readLine());
    if isempty(f)
        break;
    end
    disp(char(f));
end
```